# Fullcalendar background events

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to hide events that are inside background events so that the user cannot see it?
if yes what is the way to do it ?

```
var isValidEvent = function(start,end,id){
return $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
    return (event.rendering === "background" && id!='test' &&
            (start>event.start) && (end<event.end)) ;
}).length > 0;
};

eventRender:function(event, element, view) if(isValidEvent(event.start,event.end,event.id)){
                 $(element).hide();
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

As of the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/), `eventRender` callback should either return an event OR `false` if the event should be hidden:

```
eventRender:function(event, element, view)
       if(isValidEvent(event.start,event.end,event.id)){
            return event;
       }
       else {
            return false;
       }
},
```

I haven't tested yet as I don't need it, but should work that way.

Comment: i have two eventsources `eventSources: [{
     
     url: "indispo.php",
     className: 'holiday',/**/
     overlap:false,
     rendering: 'background',
     color: '#ff0000',
     
    },
    {
     url:'events.php',
     }
 ],`

Comment: and i want the eventsource events.php not be displayed in indispo.php which is rendering background

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this:

```
eventRender:function(event, element, view){
    var array= new Array();
    array = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('clientEvents','test');
for(i of array){
     if(event.source.url=="events.php" && moment(event.start)>=moment(i.start) && moment(event.end)<=moment(i.end)){
        return false;
     }
}     }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question, and why you needed something different than the other answer? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.